# I can't make migrate back, after I deleted them in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I am using Django with VSC.
I got some problem with my database, so i did want to delete inside of migrations but by mistake
i deleted directly folder of migrations. Anyway then i used the code;

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Then i got my migrations informations back. But the problem is, this time it didn't detect
my own migrations. So when i click something have connection with database. I got a mistake like
"No such table: MyMigrationsName"
How can i fix it ?

Comment: Removing migrations is really *not* a good idea...

Comment: Yes sir i just see it... Let's see what will happen haha.

Answer (score 1):

OP can create there a folder named `migrations` in the place OP deleted and an `__init.py__` file inside of it.

Then, if possible, drop the current database and run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: @metkopetru if this solved your problem, consider marking the answer as correct in order to help other people that come across this.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can DROP database, delete all migration files, run makemigrations and create a new database with the new migration files.

Then never make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
python manage.py makemigrations "your_app_name"
py manage.py migrate "your_app_name"'
```

Make sure the app name is included. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to search inside each migration file related with the class that you deleted and remove the operation. Operation is a element of the operations array.
When you delete the related operation, you will see another error in console.